# Como trocar de imagem no efeito Water-Ripple-, quando troca o efeito some

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Como trocar de imagem no efeito Water-Ripple-, quando troca o efeito some, a foto que ele vem, esta puxada da internet:

```
<div class="a ripples" style="background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/800/500)">
```

quando eu troco a imagem para puxar uma do meu pc o efeito some;

Tenho o seguinte código.

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- saved from url=(0082)http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Water-Ripple-Animation-ripples/ -->
    <html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <title>jQuery ripples plugin demos</title>
    <link href="./jQuery ripples plugin demos_files/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style>
    body { margin: 0; }
    div {
     position: fixed;
     font-family: "Helvetica Neue","Helvetica","Arial",sans-serif;
    }
    
    .a {
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
     right: 51%;
     bottom: 51%;
     background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .b {
     left: 51%;
     top: 25.5%;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 25.5%;
     background-attachment: fixed;
    }
    
    .c {
     left: 0;
     top: 51%;
     right: 51%;
     bottom: 0;
     background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .error {
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
     color: #eee;
     padding: 20px;
     display: none;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body >
    
    <div class="jquery-script-clear"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="a ripples" style="background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/800/500)">
    </div>
    
    
    
    <div class="error"></div>
    
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ripples.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
     try {
      $('.a,.b,.c').ripples({
       resolution: 256,
       perturbance: 0.04
      });
     }
     catch (e) {
      $('.error').show().text(e);
     }
    });
    </script>
    
    
    </body></html>
```

Comment: Tente descrever melhor o problema e formate o código; quem sabe assim alguém possa ajudar

Comment: Então não sei se deixei estranha a pergunta, somente gostaria de por no exemplo do efeito  Water-Ripple, outra imagem substituir a que tem por uma minha, quando eu substituo a imagem o efeito não pega mas, ele somente pega com o endereço que está :                                         <div class="a ripples" style="background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/800/500)">

Comment: esse efeito so está funcionando no FireFox no IE e no Chrome não funciona

Comment: Pelo que observei, você deu um salvar como em uma pagina web que continha esse código. Tenta renomear o diretório dos arquivos pois elas contem espaços e alguns navegadores isso pode dar algum conflito. Pois como você disse o codigo  funciona no firefox e no IE, poder estar dando conflito no Chrome por causa do nome das pastas. De inspecionar elemento na sua pagina, e vai na aba de console e veja se o javascript está retornando algum erro.

Comment: estou puxando os codigos tudo do meu computador, vo postar o JS dele pra vc dar uma olhada SAMUEL, agradeço a atenção

Comment: no chrome da pra vc baixar essa pagina ai vem com js dela   http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Water-Ripple-Animation-ripples/      salvar como: